# Error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError:

Tags: java, hibernate, smtp

I have written a code to send an email in hibernate. In the java project, I have added - `mail.jar` and `javaee-api-6.0.jar`. I have searched for the solution/answer in stack overflow but didn't succeeded, even on other relevant websites.

How to resolve the error am getting:

> ClassFormatError - 
>        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code 
>        attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file 
>        javax/mail/Authenticator
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
>            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

My java code is:

```
 import java.util.Properties;

 import javax.mail.Address;
 import javax.mail.Authenticator;
 import javax.mail.Message;
 import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
 import javax.mail.Session;
 import javax.mail.Transport;
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

 public class Email {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        final String fromEmail="shrivastavasucheta@gmail.com";
        final String password = "Virtual";
        final String toEmail = "sucheta.docs@gmail.com";
        System.out.println("TLS mail start");

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator(){

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail,password);
            }
        };

        Session session =Session.getInstance(prop,auth);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom (new InternetAddress(fromEmail));

        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new 
  InternetAddress(toEmail));

        System.out.println("Mail InternetAddress and add recipient");

        message.setSubject("Testing Campus");

        message.setText("Hello");

        System.out.println("Mail Subject");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("mail sent");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("mail fail");
        System.out.println(e);
       }
     }
   }
```

And also I have to implement code for yahoo mail and yahoo mail contains yahoo.com and yahoo.co.in extensions. As I have 2 mail id's for 'To' and 'From' email - which one to select?

```
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.yahoo.com");
```

or:

```
prop.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.yahoo.co.in");
```

Comment: Is `javax.mail.Authenticator` present in your project?

Comment: yes .import javax.mail.Authenticator;

Comment: can you post your dependency xml i.e. pom ??

Comment: @ ravi. I donno anything about pom. whts it. is it required to send email via hibernate-java. please guide. I see pom is not a jar

Comment: I'm asking about list of libraries ?? how did you define which library to load ?? have you defined sequence of loading libraries ??

Comment: my Referenced Libraries are in the sequence - [1]javaee-api-6.0.jar  [2] javax.mail.jar  [3] javax.mail-1.6.0.jar